# Automatically create multiple Objects and name from a set list

Tags: vba, excel, insert

Im currently trying to auto create and name multiple objects from a referenced list rather than just have the object text stated in the script.

Im using the below script, whats the best way to arrange the code to facilitate many objects to be added and for the objects not to be place in the same location.

The code to set the location is _
Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 50, 50, 100, 50)sets the object position,

how can i change the code to have many items repeated, named and lined up next to each other.

```
 Sub Sample()
     Dim shp As Shape

     Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 50, 50, 100, 50)

     With shp.OLEFormat.Object
         .Formula = ""

         .ShapeRange.ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePreset40

         .ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
         ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Process Steps").Range("C7").Value
     End With
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Here simple example which reads range of cells and inserts shapes for each cell in one line.

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim referencedList As Range
    Set referencedList = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Process Steps").Range("C1:C500")
    Sample referencedList
End Sub

Sub Sample(referencedList As Range)
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim oneCell As Range
    Dim leftValue As Long

    Const topValue As Integer = 50
    Const widthValue As Integer = 100
    Const heightValue As Integer = 50
    leftValue = 0

    For Each oneCell In referencedList.Cells
        If oneCell.Value = "" Then _
            GoTo continue

        Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape( _
            msoShapeRectangle, leftValue, topValue, widthValue, heightValue)

        With shp.OLEFormat.Object
            .Formula = ""
            .ShapeRange.ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePreset40
            .ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = oneCell.Value
        End With

        leftValue = leftValue + widthValue
continue:
    Next oneCell
 End Sub
```